# Max no of real roots

Tags: quadratics

$p(x) =x^6 + ax^5+ bx^4 +x^3 + bx^2 + ax + 1$
Given that p(1)=0 but p(-1) is not zero.
What is maximum number of distinct real roots of p(x)?

I divided by $x^3$ and made a cubic in t, where 
$t=x+1/x$, but after that what can i say?
My cubic is 
$t ^3+ at^2 + (b-3)t + 1-2a=0$
where t= 2 is one root, which gives repetation of x=1. 
now the cubic has a quadratic factor. how can i comment on nature of root of quadratic?

is it right to say that quad can maximum give 2 that means 
in x i have four so , max is 5?

Comment: yes. corrected.

Comment: $p(1)=1+a+b+1+b+a+1=2a+2b+3$, so you know that $b=-\frac32-a$. I don't know if this helps...

Comment: And $p(-1)=1-a+b-1+b-a+1=2(b-a)\neq 0$, so $b\neq a$.

Comment: so if a not equal to b??